# Cannot resolve PendingIntent.getActivity()

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications

I am trying to make a custom notification and cannot resolve this.

```
public void remNotifyClicked (View view){
    notification.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    notification.setTicker("Ticker");
    notification.setContentTitle("Notification");
    notification.setContentText("Congratulation!");
    notification.setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());


    Intent i = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
    notification.setContentIntent( new PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));

    NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    nm.notify(uniqueId, notification.build());

}
```

The problem here is, "getActivity" is showing as error(red colored) and it says it cannot resolve the symbol(when hovered over it).
 Thanks.

PS: I use Android Studio.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Replace

```
notification.setContentIntent( new PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
```

with

```
notification.setContentIntent(PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
```

`getActivity()` is a `static` method of the class `PendingIntent` and does not require an instance of `PendingIntent` in order to be invoked.

Try this. This will work.

Comment: Thanks. I am a stupid to commit such a silly mistake. Thanks again.